# How to get set of elements from list having sum is N using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python but want to learn. I have a list having some elements. I want to check that any set of elements has sum equal to 9?. If so then return set elements, not then return False. Sequence is not a matter.Example...
A=[2,3,4,5,9,6,1,0]

so, here we see that [2,3,4] having sum is 9 or [9,0],[5,4] etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find which number in a list sum up to a certain number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420937/algorithm-to-find-which-number-in-a-list-sum-up-to-a-certain-number)