# Optimum memory consumption program

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, knapsack-problem

Write a program to find the processes which utilize the memory optimally, given the list of the processes with their memory usage and the total memory available.

Example:-
Total memory :- 10

First column denotes process id's and 2nd column is the memory consumption of respective process.

1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5

Answer should be processes {1,2,4} with memory consumption {2,3,5} as 2+3+5=10

Comment: Interesting problem. So do you have a question?

Comment: Actually I would appreciate if someone at least gives a recurrence relation or dp approach to solve this problem

Comment: dont understand your question... you got N tupples (id, value), and you want to find M tuples where Sigma(value) = X ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

I believe you can find many sample code on Google

Comment: I know it resembles knapsack that's the reason I have tagged it...but its not exactly same right?

Comment: it is the same question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420937/algorithm-to-find-which-number-in-a-list-sum-up-to-a-certain-number