# slightly fuzzy version of subset sum

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I found this answer on stackoverflow [Algorithm to find which number in a list sum up to a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420937/algorithm-to-find-which-number-in-a-list-sum-up-to-a-certain-number)

I am struggling to learn dynamic programming and finding it a challenge to follow the logic. I tried changing S==0 to other values but this did not produce the desired results.

Is it possible to modify this code so the numbers don't have to sum exactly to the total, ie allow a small difference to deal with rounding issues.

```
def f(v, i, S, memo):
if i >= len(v): return 1 if S == 0 else 0
if (i, S) not in memo:  # <-- Check if value has not been calculated.
    count = f(v, i + 1, S, memo)
    count += f(v, i + 1, S - v[i], memo)
    memo[(i, S)] = count  # <-- Memoize calculated result.
return memo[(i, S)]     # <-- Return memoized value.

def g(v, S, memo):
subset = []
for i, x in enumerate(v):
# Check if there is still a solution if we include v[i]
    if f(v, i + 1, S - x, memo) > 0:
        subset.append(x)
        S -= x
return subset


v = [19783,21689,21169,11767,23207,12591]
sum = 56967
memo = dict()
if f(v, 0, sum, memo) == 0: print("There are no valid subsets.")
else: print(g(v, sum, memo))
```

returns [21169, 23207, 12591]

however if change 21169 to 21168 it returns "no valid subsets"

v = [19783,21689,21168,11767,23207,12591]

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Every place where it checks for whether a value can be used or the solution has been achieved, you need to make it a fuzzy test by checking whether the absolute value of the difference is less than the allowed difference.

Comment: E.g. `return 1 if abs(S) < difference else 0`

Comment: Thanks Barmar that worked perfectly.