# Selecting max elements from list using input value Python

Tags: python, max

I am building a program that selects max elements from a list which sums to a given input value

```
load_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20]
```

eg user inputs `30` select `20 and 10` or user inputs `35` select `20, 10, 4 and 1`since they are the possible largest elements that sum up to `30` or `35`

code

```
def process(m): 
    print m


def selection():
    aux = range(len(load_data))
    global value  # <- value is the input 
    while aux and value > 0:
        posit = max(aux) >= value 
        index = aux[posit]
        elem = load_data[index]
        value = value - posit # <- subtract max value from input and repeat process 
        del aux[posit]  
        process(elem)
```

output always prints

```
2
3
1
4
10
20
```

Comment: this is not an easy task and i am not sure you understand its complexity (programmatically speaking). I cannot think of a way to do it that does not use recursion..

Comment: You may find the following SO question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420937/algorithm-to-find-which-number-in-a-list-sum-up-to-a-certain-number

Comment: Not straightforward. Linear programming might provide a solution?

Comment: The question may be related to the Knapsack problem. Have a look here and see if anything applicable? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: For an input of `35`, there is more than one answer.  Consider @A. Grieco's answer to `yield combinations`.  This should give all possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a very complex task. This solution only provides a basic approach. It's poor and unreviewed in e.g. terms of performance.

```
import itertools

load_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20]
maximum = 35

def selection(data, maximum):
    for count in range(1,len(data)+1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(data, count):
            if maximum == sum(combination):
                yield combination

i = list(selection(load_data, maximum))
print (i)
```

And please, avoid using global variables. This is very bad style.

Comment: Can use `itertools.combinations` instead of permutations, it reduce repeated values

Comment: If instead you `yield combination`, you can get a list of all combinations whose sums equal `maximum`, e.g. `list(selection(load_data, 35))` --> `[(1, 4, 10, 20), (2, 3, 10, 20)]`.  I think this will generalize your answer.

Comment: Btw consider including the list comprehension version of your code:
`[c for count in range(1,len(load_data)+1) 
   for c in itertools.combinations(load_data, count) 
    if maximum == sum(c)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
load_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20]
global value 
value = 30

def process(m): 
    print m

def selection():
    # make a local copy of load_data
    data = load_data[:]
    global value  # <- value is the input 
    while data and (value > 0):
        maxval = max(data)
        posix = data.index(maxval)
        if posix >=0:
            value = value - data[posix] # <- subtract max value from input and repeat process 
            process(data[posix])
            data.pop(posix)  
selection()
```

, but as A. Grieco said, it's very simple and basic aproach to problem.

If `load_data` list is constant, and always has elements from example, then you should just sort descending the `load_data` first, so the bigger elements are processing first, for optimization purposes.

I.e:

```
load_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20]
global value 
value = 30

def process(m): 
    print m

def selection():
    # make a local copy of load_data
    data = sorted(load_data[:],reverse=True)
    global value  # <- value is the input 
    for v in data:
        if value -v >= 0:        
            value -= v 
            process(v)
        if value -v == 0:
            break

selection()
```

Comment: can just use `data = sorted(load_data, reverse=True)` instead of the comparer function

Comment: Thanks Skycc. Code is improved now.

Comment: Concise example.  Is there a reason to use `global`?  Why not use a function parameter pass in value e.g. `def selection(value): ...` then call `selection(30)`.