# Mapping pin list to a generated combination list

Tags: python, mapping, python-itertools, gpio

Building up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932324/selecting-max-elements-from-list-using-input-value-python?noredirect=1#comment69081630_40932324), I have generated a selection of elements from a given list summing up to a user's input value. From the generated combination of numbers I want to change the status of pins on a raspberry pi on/off. i.e when `maximum = 35` generate `[1, 4, 10, 20]` then choose `1:2, 4:17, 10:27, 20:22` then turn `pins 2, 17, 27 & 22 on` or if `maximum = 30` output should give me `[10, 20]` & `10:27, 20:22` and turn `pins 27 & 22 on`

Using the `dict` I have

```
import itertools
maximum = 35

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20]
pinList = [2, 3, 4, 17, 27, 22]
dictionary = dict(zip(data, pinList))

def selection(data, maximum):
    for count in range(1,len(data)+1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations(data, count):
            if maximum == sum(combination):
                return list(combination)

i = list(selection(data, maximum))
print (i)
k = dict((key, value) for key, value in dictionary.iteritems() if key == i)
print k
aux = range(len(k))
for r in aux:
   GPIO.setup(r, GPIO.OUT) 
   GPIO.output(r, GPIO.HIGH)
```

I am only getting

```
[1, 4, 10, 20] 
{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `==` to `in`:

```
k = dict((key, value) for key, value in dictionary.iteritems() if key in i)
```

Or more efficiently:

```
k = dict((key, dictionary[key]) for key in i)
```