# What does if-if-else one-line do in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I ran into this expression in a question here about [knapsack problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421173/343215):

```
def f(v, i, S):
  if i >= len(v): return 1 if S == 0 else 0
  count = f(v, i + 1, S)
  count += f(v, i + 1, S - v[i])
  return count
```

<strike>When I try to write out line two `if i >= len(v): return 1 if S == 0 else 0` in a more general form I get an error:</strike>

```
In [3]: if test1 : print x if test2 else print y 
  File "<ipython-input-3-9d4131fa0c48>", line 1
    if test1 : print x if test2 else print y
                     ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Here is a generalized form:

```
In [16]: if True : print("first") if True else print("second") 
first

In [17]: if True : print("first") if False else print("second")
second

In [18]: if False : print("first") if True else print("second")
[nothing]

In [19]: if False : print("first") if False else print("second")
[nothing]
```

What do you call this?

I'm surprised you can just take out the second positive case for `if...then...else` and turn it into `if...else`.

---

**UPDATE: Sorry bout the python3 noob mistake, I just wasn't paying attention. As noted, the answers don't make sense without the mistake, so I've striked out the erroneous code.**

Comment: It's called a conditional expression or ternary expression, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions .

Comment: Note your immediate problem is that `print()` is a function in Python 3, and calling it requires parentheses.

Comment: you need to fix the parentheses for print when running your script with Python 3.

Comment: I rolled back the question to your original post because your edits render the accepted and upvoted answer (You are missing `()` in your print statement) meaningless.

Comment: @SiHa, Yes. I've made the necessary continuity correction. Correct answer is for the example. I know what a conditional expression is. What I wanted was a name for the single line as in: "so what do i call it besides if-if-else?" LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it is important to point out that what you describe (`if-if-else`) is *not* a conditional expression per se, but it does include one:

`1 if S == 0 else 0` *is* a conditional expression

`if i >= len(v): return 1 if S == 0 else 0` is a [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) which comprises a simple `if` statement with a conditional expression.

So, if the first `if` evaluates to `True`, then the conditional expression will be  evaluated and the appropriate element (in this case `1` or `0`) returned to the preceding statement (`return`, here).

Comment: I think you captured what I was after. As far as I'm concerned, it's not a duplicate, but a misunderstanding (on my part) that this is better understood as compound (conditional) statement.

Answer (score 4):

You have found the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), which is known as a [Conditional Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) in Python. The expression `x if condition else y` means that if the condition (which can be a complex statement or function) evaluates to True, the expression returns `x`, and if the condition evaluates to False, the expression returns `y`.

It works like the following if-statement:

```
if test1:
    if test2:
        print(x)
    else:
        print(y)
```

Your error stems from not wrapping the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) arguments in a parentheses. This is a change made to Python 3, whereas in Python 2, your syntax would have been fine. Rewrite it to look like:

`if test1: print(x if test2 else y)`

and your error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

It is an if-expression: `a if condition else b` means: if *condition* is true, then the expression has value *a*, otherwise *b*

Your problem is unrelated, Seems you are using python 3, you got the example from python 2. In python 3 print is a function, so just add parentheses

Answer (score -2):

if you are using python of version >3, then print should have parenthesis i.e ()